# Apache don't load all virtualhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, virtualhost, restart

i have a problem with apache and the virutalhosts on ubuntu server.
The software installed on my machine is:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Apache 2.4.7

The virtualhost are configured in /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/ directory and i have 4 files:

- 000-default.conf
- default-ssl.conf

I maked these files:

- site-one.example.com.conf
- site-two.example.com.conf

The only difference is the name of subdomain an domain, so, the configuration of both files is:

site-one.example.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:9292>
    ServerName site-one.example.com:9292
    ServerAlias www.site-one.example.com:9292
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/
    alias /a /var/www/prod/a
    alias /a-test /var/www/test/a
    alias /f /var/www/prod/f
    alias /p /var/www/prod/p
    alias /p-test /var/www/test/p
    alias /t /var/www/prod/t
    alias /w /var/www/prod/www/w
    alias /t-test /var/www/test/t/  

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

site-two.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:9292>
    ServerName site-two.example.com:9292
    ServerAlias www.site-two.example.com:9292
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/
    alias /s /var/www/prod/www
    alias /s-test /var/www/test/www/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when i try to load the url "site-one.example.com/a" the server not found the files but the url by "site-two.example.com/s" works good, i've been trying restarting Apache(sudo service apache2 restart or reload or stop/start) but when i do that site-one.example.com works fine and the other stop working and said "The requested URL /a was not found on this server."

¿How can i find some log file about the virutalhost?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the server fist read the configuration of 000-default.conf file, so i commented all the lines, i restarted apache and works fine.

however, i would like to know, why sometimes apache takes one *.conf file or other???